# "already exists in the namespace" message when creating a class diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, namespaces, uml

I am trying to create class diagram in Visual Studio 2010 professional as a part of ASP .NET web application project. When I try to name a class "Customer" and .cs file, I get this message "'Customer' already exists in the namespace".

I had made the class diagram with Customer class once but deleted it. I also deleted other related .cs files. Now I am trying to create a new class diagram with the same classes as I had before.

I really don't know what to do about this problem. How can I create a new class diagram with the same classes again? Is there any way to remove existing 'Customer' from namespace?

Comment: In code, can you type `new Customer();` and then right click and choose "Go to Declaration" on the text "Customer". If you can, you'll see where the class Customer is defined as the name of the cs file will be at the top

Comment: Yes, I actually found the definition in designer.cs file for the database! But should I delete the definition from the file, or delete the whole .dbml file/database and simply start all over again?

Comment: I deleted .dbml file and started all over again. It worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Browse to the location of the project on your system and delete the old class diagram

from vs, right click on the project, then select "Open folder in windows explorer"

Locate file and delete

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I don't see any class files in the project. I'd deleted the old class diagram and class files from App_Code folder before. Or am I missing something? I have looked in other folders too.